# Right context with rivets.js declarative binding

Tags: backbone.js, rivets.js

I'm using:
1.Adapter:

```
rivets.adapters[':'] = {
      subscribe: function(obj, keypath, callback) {
        obj.on('change:' + keypath, callback)
      },
      unsubscribe: function(obj, keypath, callback) {
        obj.off('change:' + keypath, callback)
      },
      read: function(obj, keypath) {
        return obj.get(keypath)
      },
      publish: function(obj, keypath, value) {
        //console.log(obj);
        obj.set(keypath, value);

      }
    }
```

2.Collection :

```
var FriendsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Friend,
    initialize : function (Friend,options) {

        this.addFriend();

    },
    addFriend : function () {
        this.add ( this.f = new this.model() );
    }
}); 
window.friends = new FriendsList();
rivets.bind($("#friendsTable tfoot"), {friends:window.friends})
```

3.Declaration

```
<tr class="totals">
        <td colspan="2">
        <a href='javascript:' class="btn btn-primary" rv-on-click="friends.addFriend">Add Friend</a></td>
        <td class="b r">Total</td>
        <td class="total r b"></td>
    </tr>
```

When using . notation context of addFriend is set to target element - how it is possible to use : notation to force "this" to point to collection instance?

Comment: Where exactly do you want `this` to point to a collection? Can you please mark this line in code somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you what to do this or why your code is structure like this,

but if you really want to do it, you can configure rivets in that way.

Default rivets configuration:

```
rivets.configure({
 // Attribute prefix in templates
 prefix: 'rv',

 // Preload templates with initial data on bind
 preloadData: true,

 // Root sightglass interface for keypaths
 rootInterface: '.',

 // Template delimiters for text bindings
 templateDelimiters: ['{', '}'],

 // Augment the event handler of the on-* binder
 handler: function(target, event, binding) {
   this.call(target, event, binding.view.models)
 }
})
```

Modify the handler to

```
handler: function(target, event, binding) {
   this.call(binding.model, event, binding.view.models)
 }
```

So that the model used for binding will be the context of handler